# Reference existing IAM roles in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, roles

How can I reference an existing IAM role in Terraform without getting the "Reference to undeclared resource" error message? There are some service roles that come "built-in" with every AWS environment `AWSBackupDefaultServiceRole` and thus should not be re-dcleared in Terraform. How do I attach policies and do mote role operations on that role without declaring it?

Comment: Either by writing their arns manually wherever you want it. Or by using a data-source to reference them based on their name.

Comment: I am not clear on why this is a problem. Can you show the code that produces the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform may be complaining because the role does not exist yet. Some service-linked roles do not come with your account by default. Instead you have to trigger the creation of the role(s) or create it yourself.

"When using the AWS Backup console for the first time, you can choose to have AWS Backup create a default service role for you." [1]
"You must create the default role using the AWS Management Console. You cannot create the default role using the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)." [1]

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/iam-service-roles.html